# How do I hand off a file from an ASP page to a C# function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am writing a part of a web application that takes a user provided file from the browser, saves it to the server and then hands the file off to an automated excel script, then returns the processed file to the browser. I am getting the file using an `<asp:FileUploader>` which hands if off to a VB script. Is there a way to call a C# script from within the VB code?

Comment: By the way, try to avoid the word "*script*" when talking about C#/VB. Both are not scripting languages. Instead, try "C# project" or "C# application". This will lead to less confusion when communicating your problem in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a separate C# class library project that is referenced by your VB.NET ASP site (but exists within the same solution). That's the only (easy) way you can mix C# and VB code.